# Finding the minimal distance between a parabola and a point without using calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, conic-sections

> The smallest distance between the origin and a point on the parabola $y=x^2-5$ can be expressed as $\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}b$, where $a$ is not divisible by the square of any prime. Find $a+b$.

I have been browsing the web, and I can't find any methods that don't use Calculus. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given parabola can be parameterized as follows

$$\left\{ (t,t^2-5) \mid t \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

The *squared* Euclidean distance from a point on the parabola to the origin is

$$t^2 + (t^2 - 5)^2 = \cdots = t^4 - 9 t^2 + 25 = \cdots = \left( t^2 - \frac 92 \right)^2 + \frac{19}{4}$$

The minimal *squared* Euclidean distance is $\frac{19}{4}$, which is attained at $t = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Would the answer be 5?

Comment: How did you get $5$?

Comment: I don't know. I thought it would be 3sqrt(2)/2. But that wouldn't fit the requirements.

Comment: You're confusing minimum and minimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...the distance $d$ from the origin to any point on the parabola is given by $$d^2=x^2+(x^2-5)^2$$

So rather than use calculus you can complete the square to find the minimum $d$

Comment: So I need to minimize $x^2+(x^2-5)^2$?

Comment: Yes you are trying to find the minimum distance

Comment: When I minimize $x^2+(x^2-5)^2=x^4-9x^2$, I get $y=\frac{19}{4}$ as the minimum. This value is achieved when $x=3\sqrt{2}/2$

Comment: I double checked. My minimization is correct.

Comment: So you've solved it, then?